# "a unique car" or "an unique car"?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

does unique need "a" before it or "an" ?
It starts with a vowel but it annoys when using "an" .

I want the answer for a very formal article .
Thanks !

Comment: Thanks Carlo ! Does every word which starts with "U" need "a" instead of "an" or only the ones wich sound like "YOU"! Thanks !

Comment: The choice of a or an is determined by sound not spelling. So for example "an umpire" but "a user".

Comment: When we say *vowel* or *consonant* in language studies, we're specifically talking about vowel and consonant **sounds**.  We almost never use these terms to talk about **letters**!  The "AEIOU" definition of *vowel* is only really useful for playing Wheel of Fortune :-)

Comment: @snailboat I buy a vowel: A.

Comment: Plus this question has been already asked, in a form or another.

Comment: This question has been closed because it's already been asked. Put another way, it's not _a_ unique question. 8^)